# Unsure about log rule proof, can it be done without using the precondition?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Given $m\geq 1 \text{ and } 0< \alpha < 1$ show that
$$\log_\alpha\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)=-\frac{\ln m}{\ln \alpha}$$

my attempt
$\log_\alpha\left(\frac{1}{m}\right) = - \log_\alpha(m) = -\frac{\ln m}{\ln \alpha}$

Comment: Presumably $a$ and $\alpha$ are the same thing.

Comment: Which "the precondition"?

Comment: a and $\alpha$ is the same thing I've edited it out and the precondition is  0<α<1

Comment: Please add your question about the precondition in the body of the question as well, not just in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha > 0$ and $\alpha \ne 1$ are necessary as log base; otherwise, the proof is valid for both $0<\alpha < 1$ and $\alpha > 1$.

$m > 0$ is necessary to take log; otherwise, the proof is valid for both $0<m<1$ and $m\ge 1$.

Let $x = \log_\alpha \frac 1m$, then

$$\begin{align*}
\alpha^x &= \frac 1m\\
\ln\left(\alpha^x\right) &= \ln \frac 1m\\
x \ln \alpha &= -\ln m\\
x &= -\frac{\ln m}{\ln \alpha}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\log(\frac1m)=-\log(m)$ in any base (positive, not $1$) since  $\log(\frac1m)+\log(m) = \log(\frac mm)=\log(1)=0$

so your question is really showing $\log_\alpha (m) =  \frac{\ln(m)}{\ln(\alpha)}$.  If you already know that then you are done.  Otherwise consider $\ln(m) = \ln\left(\alpha ^{\log_\alpha (m)}\right) = \log_\alpha (m)\, \ln(\alpha)$